# Reference Alinment Problem in Elsevier Template Nucluer Physic B

Tags: bibliographies, elsarticle

I face an alignment problem for Referencing in the Nuclear Physics B journal template.
Some References are Shift the right side from the left side. 
[image]

**And Here are Latex File Structures I used (elsearticle-temple-num.tex)**  :

[image]

**And Here are** [elsarticle-num.bst](https://ideone.com/Ja0sgo)

Comment: Did you notice the 23 error messages? (Try to) fix them first, before even taking a look at the output.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, Sir. Lots of error I found.

Comment: The problem with the alignment is due to the inclusion of a `_` in the `doi` of [11].

Comment: Thanks a lot @Guido. I just replace doi : doi = {10.1007/978-3-319-50478-0_1} to  doi = {10.1007/978-3-319-50478-0} and get perfect alignment.